# Mode-line not updated after checking out new branch using Magit

Tags: magit

I create and checkout a new local branch via magit. Pressing

```
M-x magit-status then
b c for branch create
```

and in the magit buffer I see the new name of the branch that I am apparently on. However my file buffer still shows the former branch name. Only if I reload the buffer content via C-x C-f the new branch is shown in the mode-line. Is this intentional or how can I change that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few years ago this was asked a lot, so added the [answer](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/The-mode_002dline-information-isn_0027t-always-up_002dto_002ddate.html) to the FAQ.  Copying it here:

---

Magit is not responsible for the version control information that is being displayed in the mode-line and looks something like Git-master. The built-in "Version Control" package, also known as "VC", updates that information, and can be told to do so more often:

```
(setq auto-revert-check-vc-info t)
```

But doing so isn’t good for performance. For more (overly optimistic) information see
[Version Control and the Mode Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/VC-Mode-Line.html).

If you don’t really care about seeing that information in the mode-line, but just don’t want to see incorrect information, then consider disabling VC when using Git:

```
(setq vc-handled-backends (delq 'Git vc-handled-backends))
```

Or to disable it completely:

```
(setq vc-handled-backends nil)
```